# Create a Joint Kernel Density Function in R

Tags: r, statistics, kernel-density

I have two vectors, A and B. Can I create a joint kernel density function empirically in R such that I have some function f(x,y) that comes from vectors A and B? The following example wouldn't work, as it isn't a joint probability distribution

```
z <- cbind(A,B)
approxfun(density(z))
```

Comment: can you provide example vectors? People will be more like to help if you give them a specific example they can work with.

Answer (score 2):

`MASS::kde2d` does two-dimensional kernel density estimation given two vectors (of x and y coordinates). Rather than return a function that can be evaluated at an arbitrary (`{newx,newy}`), though, it returns the function evaluated on a square grid.

Once you've done the fussy bits like selecting a bandwidth, the actual computations for kernel density estimation at a single point `x0,y0` aren't that hard, I think it would be something like

```
sum(dnorm((x0-x)/h)*dnorm((y0-y)/h)
```

`MASS::kde2d` does clever stuff with `outer()` and `tcrossprod()` to compute the distances from all the data points to all of the points on the evaluation grids, and all of the sums, in a small number of top-level operations, but I *think* what I have above is the crux of it.